# AppCache events firing late - WebkIt (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-appcache, offline-caching

In my web app, I use the applicationCache feature. I register to the appCache events like

```
appCache.addEventListener(<event_name>, handleCacheEvent, false);

function handleCacheEvent(e) {
        console.log('handleCacheEvent appcache event: '+ e.type+' appCache.status: '+appCache.status);

    }
```

(in event_name I register to all events - 'cached', 'checking', 'downloading', etc). 
However, in Chrome logs, I see these logs:

> Application Cache Progress event (1 of 15)
>   ...
>   Application Cache Progress event (15 of 15)

at the very beginning of the run, then some of my JS business logic, and after few seconds I see my logs

> appcache event: progress appCache.status: 1
> ...

It seems that the event listener are not triggered right when the status of the appCache changes, but rather later at some point. Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've seen the same thing. When I add event listeners to those events and log them, my log message always appears after all of the browser's log message. I think this is because the browser starts loading the appcache before the contents of the page are done loading, since the appcache does its work in the background. This still gives you a chance to handle appcache events programmatically while letting the browser do its thing to honor the specification.